# How does MemberWiseClone create a new object with the cloned properties?

Tags: c#, dynamic, reflection, clone

I wanted to create a more constrained version of `MemberwiseClone`, but realised the only way my own C# code can add properties to an object is to use `dynamic`, but that can't give the object the same type as the original. My other, uglier choice is to emit source for the new clone and compile it during runtime, but that carries complexities re. assembly references etc. that I do not care for in keeping things simple.

For now I'm just using `MemberwiseClone`, but am really curious as to how it works. I can't find any decompiled source.

Comment: You do not need a decompiler for that these days. The [reference source](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/object.cs,1556d8bb3f97be20) will tell you that the method is implemented by the runtime itself (MethodImplOptions.InternalCall). From there you head over to the CoreClr github repo and search for your call. In your case you will eventually find [this file](https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/classlibnative/bcltype/objectnative.cpp), that contains the implementation you are interested in (ObjectNative::Clone).

Comment: Thank you, @thehennyy, I now know more about how to find stuff in the reference code, but my C++ is about a decade behind me, and I have no idea what `ObjectNative::Clone` does. All I want to know with this question is what principle is used to clone the object. Seeing it's C++,is it doing a direct byte for byte copy or what?

Comment: Who in the world could possibly find this question "too broad" and vote to close? I am asking one very specific question, that can only have a very limited set of answers. The title is the question; read it dummy.

Comment: thehennyy already found the C++ source code for this method. What it does is allocate new empty object for cloning and then just copies memory from current object to the memory allocated for clone (via memcpy or memmove). So to answer your question: it works by direct copying of memory from old to new object.

Comment: Thank you, @Evk, that is the answer I have been seeking all along, with a little detail, like what exactly does it copy, e.g. fields and properties? Public and private, etc. Make you comment an answer, and try add those details, and you get the bounty.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It's basically explained in the `MemberwiseClone` MSDN [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.memberwiseclone%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> The MemberwiseClone method creates a shallow copy by creating a new object, and then copying the nonstatic fields of the current object to the new object. If a field is a value type, a bit-by-bit copy of the field is performed. If a field is a reference type, the reference is copied but the referred object is not; therefore, the original object and its clone refer to the same object.

The actual implementation of the above is implemented internally by CLR. You can think of it as an optimized variant of the following standard C# code:

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

public static object CustomMemberwiseClone(object source)
{
    var clone = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(source.GetType());
    for (var type = source.GetType(); type != null; type = type.BaseType)
    {
        var fields = type.GetFields(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.DeclaredOnly);
        foreach (var field in fields)
            field.SetValue(clone, field.GetValue(source));
    }
    return clone;
}
```

i.e. get the actual type, create a new instance of that type *without calling any constructor* and copy each instance field value from the source object.

Again, the actual internal implementation is different (as pointed in the comments), the above snippet is just to demonstrate the principle and how you can implement a method with the same semantics via reflection (which of course will be much slower than the CLR method).

**ADDED BY THE OP:** Please see Ivan's comments below for the further explanation I was seeking. I consider these part of his answer and will accept it based on them.

Comment: Thanks, I understand that though, I've even written code to do it myself, to ensure only declared, public, and non-collection properties, and not fields, are copied - my detail view-models should have only simple properties, but all I'm asking is, in high level terms, how does the CLR method do it internally, i.e. is it a binary, byte for byte copy, or what?

Comment: Basically using low level copy memory (bytes). Similar to `struct` variable assignment.

Comment: With some special care to GC Refs (pointers) inside, but again, nothing different than for instance copying `struct` with `string` inside. Anyway, now I see my answer does not address your question, so I'm going to delete it.

Comment: No, @Ivan, don't delete it, your comment on it explains quite well, and I consider the comment part of the answer.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks :) Still I'm ready to do that in case @Evk decides to compose an answer from his comment.